# SELECT command to calculate percentage

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum

I'm trying to get the percentage of each video I have in my database based on its view count against all other videos.

I'm then trying to display all the videos from highest view count to lowest, displaying its percentage on its side inside a nice HTML page.

Obviously the percentage would range from 0 - 100% (and not over) and the most popular video would probably have 100% I assume..

I have about 3,400 videos in the database. My attempts are laughable and have been scratching my head for about days now..

My table looks something similar to this.

```
video_public
id | video_title | video_views
```

Attempt:

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   video_views * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM video_public)
FROM `video_public` stat
```

To be honest I don't even know if this SQL query is right.

I haven't even taken into consideration the **videos views** against **all video views** and **total videos**..

*Really stuck..*

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're looking for, and I'm not sure you are either because you say "the most popular video would *probably* have 100% *I assume*".  It sounds like you want to express the number of views each video has as a percentage *compared to the number of views of the most popular video".  Is that correct?

Comment: Larry Lustig, That is correct.

Comment: Very good, I posted a solution below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, based on the clarification of your question:

You want to calculated (video_views * 100) / (largest_views_for_any_single_video) for each video in the database.

The numerator is easy, it's just the video_views column.  The denominator is

```
SELECT MAX(video_views) FROM video_public
```

So, put it together and you get:

```
SELECT video_title, ((video_views * 100) / (SELECT MAX(video_views) 
FROM video_public)) FROM video_public
```

That should produce 100 for the most-viewed video(s), and lower percentages for other videos, down to 0 for anything never viewed.

Comment: This is what Im looking for. I didn't even think of the MAX syntax! However I would give some credit to sheepsimulator, since he seemed to crack most part of it. But in terms of what I needed. This definitely hit it home. 

Kudos.

Answer (score 5):

To modify what sheepsimulator suggests, you might try:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    video_title, 
    video_views, 
    (select sum(video_views) from video_public)) as TotalViews,
    ((100 * video_views)/(select sum(video_views) from video_public)) as PercentOfViews
FROM 
    video_public 
order by 
    video_views.
```

Change ordering to suit your tastes, of course.

Comment: Sheepsimulator had not added the calculated field on the end yet when I posted this, but he's got it right.

Comment: I would suggest to do the percentage computation in the middleware (php?); reason would be to use the RDBMS only to get the data and the middleware to work on the visualization.
but I guess it's also a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I wouldn't argue with that, Steve.  It would also depend on what I was doing.  If this was a walk-up report request (or I was in a serious hurry to get this ready for someone to look at), I'd probably do itin the database.  If I was adding this to one of our published reports, we'd have the data generated nightly and stored neatly in a table storing the data about vidoes we wanted to report on (we don't have a datawarehouse per se, yet).  If I was serving this up in an application, I would probably have the business layer do it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'd start by thinking about what your'e looking for:

> percentage of each video I have in my database based on its view count against all other videos.

Basically, you want to find it's **view rank** first.  Why not sort the records based on video views:

```
SELECT id, video_title, video_views
FROM video_public order by video_views DESCENDING
```

Now, and I think this is what you want to do, is to only show a portion of these, say, the top 10%?  You want to then assign each of your records a **percentile**.  This means that for the ordering you've assigned to the videos, you want to make the "top row" (first one returned) be given 100% and the last row returned 0%.  It gives a number between 0 and 100 to each item in your resultset.

Your'e percentile is computed:

```
SELECT id, 
       video_title, 
       video_views, 
       ((video_views * 100) / (select max(video_views) from video_public)) video_percentile
FROM video_public order by video_views DESCENDING
```

If you only want to show then the top 10%, try the following:

```
SELECT id, 
       video_title, 
       video_views, 
       ((video_views * 100) / (select max(video_views) from video_public)) video_percentile
FROM video_public
WHERE ((video_views * 100) / (select max(video_views) from video_public)) > 90
ORDER BY video_views DESCENDING
```

It isn't totally clear what you're looking for, but I think this could be helpful.

---

**EDIT:**
After looking over the comments, specifically Riven's and Larry Lustig's, and re-reading the question, I'd have to say that the sum() of the video_views is incorrect, so I went back and changed the sum()s to max()s.  This will give you a percentage based upon the video viewed the most.

Comment: But that won't give you any percentage. Just the order of most viewed, or less, depending on your sortingdirection.

Comment: I've accepted this because its closest to resolving my question.  The only -tiny- problem I have is the top viewed videos are a little over 100%. But I think you've just about done it sheepsimulator. Thank you.

Comment: Beavers, that shouldn't be the case with this solution.  Every video should come in under 100%, *unless* there's just one video in the table.

Comment: According to the clarification made by the OP above, this doesn't answer the question he or she meant to ask.

Comment: @ Larry - After reviewing other answers, I have changed mine to reflect your (and Riven's) percentage calculation, which is what the OP was looking for.  I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to calculate your percentage in your script, and just retreive the view-counts from the database.

Comment: I'd go this route if I really wasn't sure about my SQL skills, but I feel they are good to cultivate.  Usually if you're doing stuff with databases though, having the database do the math for you and limiting large volume data transfer can pay off in the future.

Comment: I'd rather calculate it through SQL, I can then later manage everything alot better.

Comment: Why?  You can (probably) get this information in the same SQL command you use to retrieve the counts with the addition of perhaps 60 characters of text.  If encapsulated as a view, that information would then be available to any database reader.  Why write extra routines and confine the results to a single application?

Answer (score 1):

Run two selects:

```
 select max(video_views) FROM video_public
```

to get the maximum number of views and then run your other select and calculate the percentage in your script. Otherwise, the subselect might run for each result row ... which is not what you want, performance wise.

Also note that you must use `max`, not `sum` or `count(*)` since you want to know "how often has this video been watched compared to the one which I watched most". Imaging you watched every video once and one twice. What's the percentage going to be? 100%? Or 0.0000001%?

Comment: For the other answers this statement doesn't make sense "the most popular video would probably have 100% I assume.." but for this answer it does.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, ((video_views * 100) / (select sum(views) from videos)) view_percent   from video_public
```

this will give you what percentage of the total views has each video.

Comment: Don't forget TSQL will round integer / integer to integer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it works in MySQL now.

```
select id, video, views, ((views / (select sum(views) from video)) * 100) as Percentagess
from video
```

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Video` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Views` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `video`
--

INSERT INTO `video` (`ID`, `Video`, `Views`) VALUES
(1, 'Hulk', 20),
(2, 'Jack', 30),
(3, 'The King', 24);
```

The Code below works in SQL Server:

It is a cursor with a temporary table i just wrote.

declare @total int
set @total = (select sum(Views) from video)

```
declare @videoid int
declare @video varchar(50)
declare @views int

declare @percentage decimal(18, 2)


IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE NAME LIKE '%tmp%')
DROP TABLE #tmp


--create temporary table
CREATE TABLE #tmp (VideoID int, VideoTitle varchar(50), Views int, Percentage decimal(18, 2))

DECLARE @videoPercent CURSOR
SET @videoPercent = CURSOR FOR 
    select id, video, views
    from video

OPEN @videoPercent

FETCH NEXT FROM @videoPercent INTO @videoid, @video, @views
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

    set @percentage = (convert(decimal(18,2), @views) / convert(decimal(18,2), @total)) * 100; 

    insert into #tmp(VideoID, VideoTitle, Views, Percentage)
    values(@videoid, @video, @views, @percentage);

    FETCH NEXT FROM @videoPercent INTO @videoid, @video, @views
end

select * from #tmp

CLOSE @videoPercent
DEALLOCATE @videoPercent
```

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Video](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Video] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Views] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

Fill it in with data and u are ready to go. Enjoy yourself.

Comment: Im sorry about that. It may be of use to someone else hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd want calculate the percentage in 1 query, use:

```
SELECT `vp1`.`id`, `vp1`.`video_views` * 100 / (SELECT MAX(`vp2`.`video_views`) FROM video_public AS `vp2`) FROM video_public AS `vp1`
```

Ofcourse it would be much more efficient to store the intermediate result in PHP (or a SQL variable) and pass it to the next query

```
$phpmax <= SELECT MAX(`vp2`.`video_views`) FROM video_public AS `vp2`
SELECT `vp1`.`id`, `vp1`.`video_views` * 100 / {$phpmax} ) FROM video_public AS `vp1`
```

==> Everybody using SUM(views) in the query has the wrong results !! The highest ranking video should result in 100%, not a percentage of the view count of all videos combined, therefore you must use MAX(views)

Answer (score 0):

Something to bear in mind... so far all answers include subqueries, which I don't think are necessary. These will be evaluated for EACH row in your table!

Rather do this externally, e.g.

Instead of this:

```
select id, ((video_views * 100) / (select sum(views) from videos)) view_percent
from video_public
```

Do this:

```
declare @totalviews int
select @totalviews = sum(views) from videos

select id, (video_views * 100 / @totalviews) view_percent
from video_public
```

That should run faster, and have less of an impact on your database.

Comment: Is this MySQL compatible?  It looks an awful lot like TSQL.

Comment: Sorry... this is TSQL. I have a background in TSQL, but thought the problem is generic enough that it can be easily translated.

Actually, I only saw the MySQL tag after commenting. Will look at the tags properly before answering again. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for giving it an attempt anyway. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you think that sub-query will be executed once per row?  It's not correlated to the surrounding query in any way, so any reasonably good optimizer should recognize that it only needs to be evaluated once.  Are you saying that MSSQL won't make that optimization (honest question, I don't use MSSQL much).

Comment: Good point Larry. I was working on correlated subqueries when I wrote this, so probably just got my brain wires crossed. But I decided to do very basic analysis of this, and it seems that the subquery version is marginally less optimised... by about 5 - 6% in the query plans I tried. That said... I haven't really been digging deep, but I am now intrigued as your comments are perfectly valid!

Answer (score 0):

You will not end up with your most viewed video at 100% unless only one of your videos gets viewed, but it will give you the view count, ratio of views of this video over all viewings, and a percent of times this has been viewed compared to all videos.

---

```
SELECT 
    Videos.id                     AS VideoID,
    video_views                   AS ViewCount,
    video_views / Total.ViewCount AS ViewRatio,
    Convert(varchar(6),Round(100.00 * video_views / Total.ViewCount, 2)) + '%' AS ViewPercentage
FROM 
    video_public AS Videos
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT Convert(float,Sum(video_views)) AS ViewCount FROM video_public) AS Total
ORDER BY
    video_views DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is actually with two separate queries.  I agree with Stuart that subqueries will have a negative impact on database performance because the subquery will be run for each record returned.

What I would do is run a query to get the total video views and store the result in a local variable.

`SELECT SUM(video_views) FROM VIDEO_PUBLIC`
if you want the percentage viewed of all total views

or

`SELECT MAX(video_view) FROM VIDEO_PUBLIC`
if you want the percentage viewed relative to the most popular video.

Next, run a query to get the videos, order by most views:

`SELECT id, video_title, video_views FROM VIDEO_PUBLIC ORDER BY video_views DESC`

Then in code you can calculate the percentage viewed of each video by using the result from the first query while looping through the results of the second query.

I'm not sure what language your using for your display, but in C# it would look like this:

```
int totalViews = FirstQuery();
IEnumerable<Videos> videos = SecondQuery();
foreach (Video video in videos) {
    double totalPercentage = ((double)video.Video_Views / (double)totalViews) * 100)
}
```