# SQL: How to calculate the percentage using SUMS()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I'm trying to calculate percentages using SUM() to gather totals.

```
CONVERT(decimal(10,2), SUM(cola)/(SUM(cola)+SUM(colb)))
```

I've checked and SUM(cola) = 3 and SUM(colb) = 2;  So I was expecting it to calculate like...

3/5 = .6; So I was hoping to get returned, 0.60,

Here's the full query:

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN this < 0 THEN '-'
                ELSE '+' END AS 'Col1',
                SUM(cola) as 'this', SUM(colb) as 'that',
                CONVERT(decimal(10,2), SUM(cola)/(SUM(cola)+SUM(colb)) as 'PCT'
     FROM Table1
    WHERE colc = 'Condition'
 GROUP BY CASE WHEN this < 0 THEN '-'
               ELSE '+' END
```

Comment: I suggest you read up on [Integer Division](http://www.peterbe.com/Integer-division-in-programming-languages). You need at least one operand to be a float type.

Comment: @davomcd: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/1763989/247184 for ideas.

Comment: @Oded thanks! can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing [Integer division](http://www.peterbe.com/Integer-division-in-programming-languages).

You need at least one operand to be a float type if you want a float result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Oded, (forgot to convert integers to decimal) So, this is what I changed...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN this < 0 THEN '-' 
                ELSE '+' END AS 'Col1', 
                SUM(cola) as 'this', SUM(colb) as 'that', 
                CONVERT(decimal(10,2), SUM(cola)/(CONVERT(decimal(10,2),
                SUM(cola))+CONVERT(decimal(10,2), SUM(colb))) as 'PCT' 
     FROM Table1 
    WHERE colc = 'Condition' 
 GROUP BY CASE WHEN this < 0 THEN '-' 
               ELSE '+' END
```